# Executing Insert command at the same time writes the data twice to database despite a check

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, sql-insert

I need to check whether similar data exists in the database and skip that insert. This question might look like a duplicate but I did not find any solutions.
I am using PostgreSQL DB and I have an SQL query

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name, dob, mobile)
VALUES ('sam', '23-05-2000', '8070605040');
```

If I run this command twice then it should only be inserted once after checking for the combined uniqueness of dob and mobile i.e. if I enter data like ('tom', '23-05-2000', '8070605040'), it should not be entered. My existing code works when the command runs one after the other.

But if I run the command at the same time on 2 devices by the press of a button then the record is entered twice.

***Result after Running code one after the other***

```
name     dob       mobile
sam   23-05-2000  8070605040
```

***Result if the command is executed at the same time***

```
name     dob       mobile
sam   23-05-2000  8070605040
sam   23-05-2000  8070605040
```

If there is even a second delay then the existing code works fine. But executing literally at the same time does not check as it is not written to the database yet.

I also do not want to add a unique condition on the table itself as I don't understand the data correctly and would like to do this as an SQL query.
How can I check and prevent this from happening.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to prevent duplicates, the **only** reliable way of doing it is to create a unique index. If you do not "understand" the data, then how do you know that duplicates aren't allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manually check the uniqueness of the record, you can use a transaction and lock the whole table:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE tbl IN EXCLUSIVE MODE; -- only allow read access
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE a = 1 and b = 2;

--- if not existed, insert new record here
COMMIT;
```

This has poor performance and should only be used for this one specific need. The best solution is always use a `UNIQUE INDEX`.

Comment: Thanks. let me try it out.
But I do have a question. If I lock the table will other queries be saved in a queue or will they be flushed?

Comment: It will be blocked at client side, wait for your current transaction

Comment: Explicit table locks are a receipe for trouble and usually a symptom of incomplete understanding of database concurrency handling.

Comment: Agree, but I don't think you're answering this specific question. This is not a question about "Understanding Database System", it's just about finding a specific technique to resolve a specific requirement.

Comment: "But as I said I do not understand the table or the previous data and do not want to change any of the table constraints" And actually this is a very common case in poorly designed production system. If the production database contains many dirty data, you need to prevent the duplicates first before you can fix the database with UNIQUE INDEX or something else

Comment: Thanks. This answers my question but like you said it poses performance issues. So I had to go with unique index.

Answer (score 2):

> If I run this command twice then it should only be inserted once after checking for the combined uniqueness of dob and mobile

This is only true if `dob`/`mobile` is declared `unique` or has a `unique` index.  Presumably, you need:

```
alter table table_name add constraint unq_table_name_dob_mobile unique (dob, mobile);
```

With a unique index/constraint, the *database* ensures the data integrity.  The database will not allow duplicates into the table, no matter how hard the application tries.

Comment: Thanks. I do understand that. But as I said I do not understand the table or the previous data and do not want to change any of the table constraints. And currently, the check is done by a select statement.

so is there no way to check the data inside a transaction before it is written to the database?

Comment: @Glitch_Znab . . . If you want to ensure data integrity, then the database needs to be in charge.  Trying to do so from the application only results in hard-to-debug race conditions and inaccurate data.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using this and would also suggest using this.  But as my specific problem was solved by @Kassian's answer I have accepted that as the answer.  Thanks again.